# What is the temperature of outerspace?

Tags: space, temperature, weather

I want to know whether the temperature in Outer space is higher than earth's or cold.Is the temperature in outer space vary as it does on earth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The temperature in the [heliosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliosphere) is about one million Kelvin, lower (but still very hot) in the outer regions of the heliosphere, higher [close to the sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliosphere).
But the density of the [plasma](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_%28Physik%29) is very low, so you wouldn't feel the heat (except close to the sun).

Within [Earth's exosphere](http://airs.jpl.nasa.gov/maps/satellite_feed/atmosphere_layers/), reaching up to 10,000 km, the temperature is lower, roughly 1,000 to 1,500 C.

In [interstellar space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_medium) there exist [hot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_II_region) (e.g. 10,000 K) and [cold gas clouds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_cloud).

Due to the very low density, hot and cooler fractions can penetrate each other, such that there doesn't need to be a uniquely defined temperature.

The large-scale average temperature of [outer space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_space) should be 2.7 K (about -270.5 C), close to the [CMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) black body temperature.

Comment: You don't differentiate between the day and night sides of Earth's exosphere.

Comment: @called2voyage Temperature fluctuations of the exosphere seem to be dependent of solar activity, not much from diurnal factors, but I've not yet found an explicite reference to be quite shure. This paper investigates some of the waves of the upper atmosphere: http://heliophysics.nasa.gov/SolarMinimum24/papers/BruinsmaForbes_JGR_2010.pdf

Comment: where are you getting the average temperature of outer space? What are the steps taken to get this number?

Comment: @RyanMcGaha From the linked WP article: _The baseline temperature, as set by the background radiation (from the theorized Big Bang), is 2.7 kelvin (K)._

Answer (score 0):

Than answer to whether it varies or is definitely yes but not in the same way as on Earth. The temperature in completely empty space with no stars for large distances would approach absolute zero ( −459.67°F or −273.15°C depending on the system to which you are accustomed) the further you go away from any heat producing body such as a star or active black hole. If you get close to stars or active black holes or many other things, the temperature could be thousands of degrees higher than on Earth. It just depends on distance.